# How to split/tokenize a string by given requirements?

Tags: string, kotlin

I have this string here I need to split up in tokens.

```
thorak={name="Thorak"}
```

The result should look something like this:

```
["thorak", "=", "{", "name", "=", "Thorak", "}"]
```

### My thought

I thought about having different RegEx rules running over it but am a bit unsure how to do this properly.

Consider this rule array:

```
["^(\w+)", "^=", "^{", "^(\w+)", "^=", "^(\w+)", "^}"]
```

Given a RegEx rule that only matches Strings `^(\w+)` I would apply it to the string.
It should match with the `thorak` string and there I have my **first** token.

To have this work in a loop I might do the following:

- Match a RegEx rule
- Save the matching string in an array
- Remove the matching string from the iterated string (to have RegEx rules running over the next parts)
- Repeat until the String is empty OR no rule was able to be applied

This is my first time doing a bit more labor work on string so I wonder what nifty tricks there exist to make what I want easier.

Comment: It depends how complicated your input will get, which is hard to tell from this single example. If you need something similar in complexity to JSON, you could use a parser combinator library like [better-parse](https://www.kotlinresources.com/library/better-parse/) (I just searched for it, this is not a recommendation per se). Or maybe you could change your input to use an already established format, like JSON, JSON5, TOML or XML.

Comment: The input is already established with that syntax and I am not able to change it. One way would be to translate it to JSON however this might not be the scope for the question rather than a radical alternative