# How to get the first value from a list without exceptions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a date value in format "2021-07-14T13:00:00.000+0300" (or similar). I want to convert it to `Date`. In this case I have to traverse a loop of different formats and check if they fail.

```
import java.text.*
import java.util.*

val formats = listOf(
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
    "dd.MM.yyyy, EEEE, HH:mm" // And many others.
)

val date = "2021-07-14T13:00:00.000+0300"
val locale = Locale.getDefault()

for (format in formats) {
    try {
        return SimpleDateFormat(format, locale).parse(date)
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
    }
}
// If nothing found, return current date.
return Date()
```

How to convert this for-loop to something like `map`? So that we can get the first value without exception?

```
val result = formats.map { ... }
```

Comment: If it was Java than I would use Tokenizer. I think something like tokenizer exists in Kotlin also. Found a result... See the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158724/how-to-split-tokenize-a-string-by-given-requirements

Comment: @Istiak, thanks, a good variant, maybe we should use regex.

Comment: FWIW, even with a regex list, you'd still need to parse the string against the matching regex to get the date or use named capture groups. It could be that a list of regex matching (or a single regex with |'s between patterns) is faster than parsing dates against multiple patterns but take into account the conversion of each date format into a regex. Like `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` would be `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}[-+]\d{2,4}`. Making the timezone optional, the regex could be `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}(?:[-+]\d{2,4})?` to handle a 2-in-1 scenario.

Comment: Adding in the capture groups it becomes: `(?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})T(?<hh>\d{2}):(?<mm>\d{2}):(?<ss>\d{2}).(?<SSS>\d{3})(?<tz>[-+]\d{2,4})?`. Also keep in mind that you'd want to distinguish between different occurrences of the same thing in different regex's like 2-digit years vs 4-digit years or long weekday names vs weekday abbreviations. All this before being able to construct a date with the gathered data, some of which will be partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, while still using [`firstNotNullOfOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-not-null-of-or-null.html), is to use [`parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition)) with a [`ParsePosition`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/ParsePosition.html) object whose properties you can safely ignore when combined with [`setLenient(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean))*.

The advantage of the `parse​(String, ParsePosition)` version over `parse​(String)` is that it returns `null` when it can't parse the date, instead of throwing an error, so the try-catch overhead per iteration can be avoided.

Along with that, since you're defaulting to the current date if all formats fail, you can avoid the nullable Date type result with an Elvis op at the very end.

```kotlin
val result: Date = formats.firstNotNullOfOrNull { format ->
    with (SimpleDateFormat(format, locale)) {
        setLenient(false)  // may not be required, see below
        parse(date, ParsePosition(0))  // is null or Date
    }
} ?: Date()
```

Btw, `setLenient(false)` may not be required because on v15, there's no leniency for `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` ***in the docs***...but it does behave leniently. Setting it to `true` above or leaving it out, and parsing a date of `"2021-07-14T53:00:00.000+0300"` (note the '53') produced `Fri Jul 16 02:00:00 UTC 2021`. With no leniency, it produces `null`. The leniency is mentioned on the abstract base class [`DateFormat.parse(String, ParsePosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition)) but not for [`SimpleDateFormat.parse(String, ParsePosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition)).

So if you're expecting non-pattern-matching dates rather than invalid-but-pattern-matching dates, the above loop could be reduced to:

```kotlin
val result: Date = formats.firstNotNullOfOrNull { format ->
    SimpleDateFormat(format, locale).parse(date, ParsePosition(0))
} ?: Date()
```

Comment: Note: `firstNotNullOfOrNull()` processes sequentially by default, not in one go. So it already has early-exit. This is unlike `List.map` which processes the entire Collection first, unless provided a Sequence. So we don't need to do `formats.asSequence().firstNotNullOfOrNull { ... }` to get early-exit.

Comment: Thank you! So nice answer! You made an extensive research. Many interesting ideas about `Date`.

Comment: You're welcome! I hadn't looked at DateFormat before this so it was interesting for me too (new to Kotlin, enjoying all the functional programming features). Btw, another optimisation you could do - which isn't part of your question - assuming you have a long list of dates to check, say `dateList` - then re-creating the SimpleDateFormat objects repeatedly for each date and format could slow things down. Since the list of  possible`formats` is probably much shorter than the dates you need to parse, you could first create all the df objects and then directly iterate over those while parsing.

Comment: So it would be something like - 1. create the SimpleDateFormat objects: `val dfObjs = formats.map { SimpleDateFormat(it, locale).apply { setLenient(false) } }` and then 2. parse each date string using the SDF's: `val parsedDates = dateList.map { date -> dfObjs.firstNotNullOfOrNull { df -> df.parse(date, ParsePosition(0)) } ?: Date() }`.

Comment: Agree with you! An interesting point. Would use your solution. By the way, how did you find this topic? :)

Comment: The topic showed up in the Kotlin-tag feed.

Comment: Good. While this solution is right, there may be one exception, if we use wrong format ("abc"). Then we will get an exception: 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'b''. But this is a problem of a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `firstNotNullOfOrNull()`.

```
val result: Date? = formats.firstNotNullOfOrNull { format ->
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat(format, locale).parse(date)
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        null
    }
}
```